# Why is EF7/Core inserting duplicate records?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

In my domain model I have

```
class School
{
    public ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

class Student
{
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

class Teacher
{
    public ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}

class Course
{
    public Student Student { get; set; }

    public Teacher Teacher { get; set; }
}
```

Say I already have a Student and a Teacher in my database

> Student ID = {C26A6D90-6D36-4CE9-9FF0-5C5BAB6994CC}
>
> Teacher ID = {26ECCCC6-4A24-4FB2-A406-5021B693EE5E}

And then I want to create a new course

```
Course c = new Course(student, teacher);
repo.Add(c);
repo.Save();
```

1. I get an error telling me I can't re-create a school with the same ID
2. I get an error telling me I can't re-create a student with the same ID

basically, I'm getting the records from the database (`Student` & `Teacher`), and then trying to use them to create a new relational entity (`Course`)

> {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Violation of PRIMARY KEY
>   constraint 'PK_Schools'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.Schools'. The duplicate key value is
>   (78434ef7-20db-42c8-448e-08d401d04461). The statement has been
>   terminated.

This seems to be an EF7 problem...is it just not mature enough yet - because it doesn't feel like it!

Comment: Make sure you're using the same DbContext

Comment: @CodeNotFound ... OH MY DAYS...YOU HAVE GOT TO BE ******* KIDDING ME! :@  - I changed AddTransient to AddSingleton on my DbContext and Repos and it works GRRRRRRRRRR!!! - WHERE IS THE DOCUMENTATION FOR THIS!!?!?!?!

Comment: :D Add your own answer and accept it as an answer. So future developer will know how to solve this issue ;-)

Comment: To be fair to those that aren't using DI, another option is to `Attach` the `student` and `teacher` objects to the context before saving the `course`. `Attach` tells EF that the object already exists in the database and shouldn't be added again.

Comment: @DStanley thank you, this is useful information which I am going to duplicate (excuse the pun) in my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With many thanks to [CodeNotFound](https://stackoverflow.com/users/797882/codenotfound) who deserves a trophy for...

> Make sure you're using the same DbContext

So I changed `AddTransient<,>` to `AddSingleton<,>` in my services config and hey-presto! IT WORKS!

Also thanks to [D Stanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1081897/d-stanley) for this useful snippet:

> To be fair to those that aren't using DI, another option is to Attach
>   the student and teacher objects to the context before saving the
>   course. Attach tells EF that the object already exists in the database
>   and shouldn't be added again.

*Please, if you find this, spare a thought for those who went before you!*